# VC2010 Intellisense - auto-complete /full/ function declaration?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, autocomplete, intellisense

Every so often, in MSVC 2005/8, the erratic Intellisense would randomly decide to kick in and do something wondrous: auto-complete the ENTIRE declaration at once, while having laboriously been re-typing/selecting the function definition for the 1000th time. No, I wasn't drunk at the time. But I did see it happen occasionally--maybe 10 to 20 times in 2 years. More times than the average kook claims to have been given a welcoming committee by aliens.

Tell me: Should I be on the lookout for extraterrestrials, or is this an actual phenomenon? Because, if this feature were real, and consistently reproducible, it would be THE BEST FEATURE EVER!

Take note, VS devs! I don't care about member auto-completion; I know those anyway, and the squiggles are far better than auto-complete. I want my (fixed?) declaration auto-re-completion! Save my fingers from the injustice!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I've ever noticed that from the default IntelliSense, but the commercial addin [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) does do it when [suggestions](http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/suggestion.asp) are enabled.